# How to compress file in android studio to upload in cloud?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, uri

I am using AWS Amplify as my backend and I'm using amplify S3 to store image and video.But I want to upload files in best possible compression(Example 1.5mb->120kb).Can anyone suggest me what is the best method for that? My code:

```
          try {
                InputStream exampleInputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

                Amplify.Storage.uploadInputStream(
                        editText.getText().toString(),
                        exampleInputStream, StorageUploadInputStreamOptions.defaultInstance(),
                        this::showProgress,
                        this::uploded,
                        storageFailure -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Upload failed", storageFailure)
                );
            }  catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
                Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Could not find file to open for input stream.", error);
            }
```

Comment: Don't ask for the best. Just zip the beast.

Comment: Tell me clearly plz

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend this **zip4j** library. In my case i used version `2.9.1` So you can choose whatever version you want!. But, in the library calling functions different. Because, It depends on which version you are using... Thats why im mentioned my version above.

[zip4j Library](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j)

1. **You can use my snippets todo the zipping task. And uncompress also.**
2. **Also recommend protect your files with a password and also while uncompressing it. How do you do it? check down below.**

**Compress**

- ***src*** - Your path or file to compress **Use File("FILE_OR_FOLDER_PATH").getAbsolutePath()**
- ***dst*** - Destination to compressed file
- ***ZIP_PASSWORD*** - You password to protect **(Compress)** file

```
   private boolean compressAsZip(String src, String dst) {
        File dstFile = new File(dst);
        //make dirs if necessary
        dstFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            // Setup encrypt true to protect with password
            parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
            // Set encryption method
            parameters.setEncryptionMethod(EncryptionMethod.AES);
            // Setup password key length / strength
            parameters.setAesKeyStrength(AesKeyStrength.KEY_STRENGTH_256);
            // To include the folder to .zip
            parameters.setIncludeRootFolder(false);
            parameters.setCompressionMethod(CompressionMethod.DEFLATE);
            parameters.setCompressionLevel(CompressionLevel.ULTRA);
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(dstFile.getAbsoluteFile(), "ZIP_PASSWORD".toCharArray());
            zipFile.setRunInThread(true);
            zipFile.addFolder(new File(src), parameters);
            ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = zipFile.getProgressMonitor();
            while (!progressMonitor.getState().equals(ProgressMonitor.State.READY)) {
                //System.out.println("Percentage done: " + progressMonitor.getPercentDone());
                //System.out.println("Current getFileName: " + progressMonitor.getFileName());
                //System.out.println("Current task: " + progressMonitor.getCurrentTask());
                //System.out.println("Current total work: " + progressMonitor.getTotalWork());
                //System.out.println("Current total work completed: " + progressMonitor.getWorkCompleted());
            }
            if (progressMonitor.getResult().equals(ProgressMonitor.Result.SUCCESS)) {
                //System.out.println("Successfully added folder to zip");
                return true;
            } else if (progressMonitor.getResult().equals(ProgressMonitor.Result.ERROR)) {
                //System.out.println("Error occurred. Error message: " + progressMonitor.getException().getMessage());
                return false;
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Task cancelled");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            //exception.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Uncompress**

- ***src*** - Your compressed file to uncompress **Use File("COMPRESSED_FILE_PATH").getAbsolutePath()**
- ***destination*** - Destination to store extracted files from the compressed file
- ***ZIP_PASSWORD*** - You password to uncompress file

```
private boolean unZipFolder(String src, String destination) {
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(src);
            if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                zipFile.setPassword("ZIP_PASSWORD".toCharArray());
            }
            zipFile.extractAll(destination);
            ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = zipFile.getProgressMonitor();
            if (progressMonitor.getResult().equals(ProgressMonitor.Result.SUCCESS)) {
                System.out.println("Successfully extracted data from the zip");
                return true;
            } else if (progressMonitor.getResult().equals(ProgressMonitor.Result.ERROR)) {
                System.out.println("Error occurred. Error message: " + progressMonitor.getException().getMessage());
                return false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Task cancelled");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it good to use for cloud upload and retrieval? How latent is this process how long it will take.

Comment: @ThinQ Did you tried it?.

Comment: @ThinQ As an example how big is your file size?

Comment: 10mb 20mb max 50mb.

Comment: Uri uri=data.getData();
           File file=new File(uri.getPath());
            compressAsZip(file.getAbsolutePath(),getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/compressed.txt");     " zipFile.addFolder(new File(src), parameters);" this line showing an error folder not found

Comment: file.getabsolutepath() returning /document/image:592327 is it right

Comment: @ThinQ nope it not returning to right place!, Did you used document file picker? to pick file?. I think your **uri** not giving right value!  this one **uri.getPath()**

Comment: @ThinQ `String docPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).toString();
        File compressedFile = new File(docPath, "compressed.txt");
        zipFile.addFolder(new File(compressedFile.getAbsolutePath()), parameters);`

Try this!

Comment: Can you share your code how to chose file from storage and passing it to compressAsZip()?

Comment: please help me now I'm getting path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/PXL_20220702_173826954.NIGHT.jpg but still  zipFile.addFolder(new File(src), parameters); showing error folder is not a directory